# How do I save the current date time hour seconds as a string so I could reuse it again and again

Tags: java

Scenario :

As a user, I would like to save the current `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` as a String.

That's the easy part - but I am confused about how to reuse the said String over and over without invoking the method to get the current `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`

Here are my methods

```
DateTimeUtil.class

    private static final LocalDateTime NOW = LocalDateTime.now();

    private static final DateTimeFormatter YEAR_MONTH_DAY_HOURS_MINUTES
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

    public static String getCurrentYearMonthDateHourMinutes() {
        return YEAR_MONTH_DAY_HOURS_MINUTES.format(NOW);
    }
```

```
Sample1.class

        final String enName =
                        DateTimeUtil.getCurrentYearMonthDateHourMinutes();

Sample2.class

        final String frName =
                        DateTimeUtil.getCurrentYearMonthDateHourMinutes();
```

I assume that the `enName` and `frName` objects will have a different `getCurrentYearMonthDateHourMinutes` assuming that at least a minute has passed.

My objective is to store `DateTimeUtil.getCurrentYearMonthDateHourMinutes();` in a way that my Sample1.class and Sample2.class would have the same time despite however many minutes had passed.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: And what happens, what is wrong?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson so if Sample1.class invokes the DateTimeUtil method, time as already passed and Sample2.class will now have a different time.

Comment: Once you assign a value to `NOW`, it doesn't change. You have defined it as a constant. The value is assigned when class `DateTimeUtil` is loaded. If print it, then sleep for one minute then print it again, it will print the same value. Unless your actual code is different from the code you posted in your question.

Comment: Also, you formatted the timestamp to contain seconds instead of minutes

Comment: @Abra oh okay thank you. I'll give it a shot

Comment: @AlexRudenko Thank you for the review. I Will update on my end. Cheers.

Comment: So you didn’t really test the code before posting or how did you manage to get different time values?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson on the other classes I called the LocalDateNow method that triggered a new time. It was an error on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply retain the string returned from your method. After capturing the current moment, keep the result rather than ask again.

```
String s = DateTimeUtil.getCurrentYearMonthDateHourMinutes() ;
```

Pass this string to instances of your two classes that need them. Either define an argument in the constructor of each class, or define a setter method on each class.

```
Sample1 s1 = new Sample1( s ) ; 
Sample2 s2 = new Sample2( s ) ;
```

Tip: Generally better to **pass around smart objects rather than dumb strings**. Consider passing around `Instant` objects for each class to do with as it sees fit.

---

By the way, I cannot imagine a scenario where calling `LocalDateTime.now` is the right thing to do. That type cannot represent a moment.

To capture the current moment in UTC, use `Instant.now`. To capture the current moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region, use a time zone with `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some place in the workflow where you are creating the objects of Sample1.class and Sample2.class. That is where ideally you would create a local variable to store the current time.

Main.class

```
private static final LocalDateTime NOW = LocalDateTime.now();
final String dateString =
                        DateTimeUtil.getCurrentYearMonthDateHourMinutes();

Sample1 sample1 = new Sample1(dateString);
Sample2 sample2 = new Sample2(dateString);
```

DateTimeUtil.class

```
    private static final DateTimeFormatter YEAR_MONTH_DAY_HOURS_MINUTES
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:ss");

    public static String getCurrentYearMonthDateHourMinutes() {
        return YEAR_MONTH_DAY_HOURS_MINUTES.format(NOW);
    }
```

Sample1.class

```
public class Sample1 {
final String enName;

   Sample1(String value) {
    this.enName = value;
   }
}
```

Sample2.class

```
public class Sample2 {
final String frName;

   Sample2(String value) {
    this. frName = value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the result of `getCurrentYearMonthDateHourMinutes()` in a variable and use that variable.

Something like this:

```
String dateTime = DateTimeUtil.getCurrentYearMonthDateHourMinutes();
System.out.println(dateTime);
callAnotherMethod(dateTime);
```